# How to append an array?

Tags: c

I'm looking for if it is possible to enlarge array size in C without losing old values, which is I guess append function in Python.

```
int size_arr = 1;
int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_arr);
// Let's give first element of arr to 1
*(arr+0) = 1;
size_arr++;
//Realloc, but I lost *(arr+0) = 1
arr = (int *)realloc(arr, size_arr);
```

Comment: Detail: Code is not changing the size of an array.  It is changing the memory allocated.  In C, once an _array_ is defined like `int a[42]`, its size cannot change.  `int *arr` is a pointer.   Changing the memory allocation though is what is done here and is quite common.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare the two lines of your code:

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_arr);
arr = (int *)realloc(arr, size_arr);
```

Do you see the difference in last arguments of both calls? Since when reallocating you shrink your array to two bytes, array contents is lost and behaviour becomes slightly undefined.

Give `realloc` a proper size and you'll see it preserves your original data.

Comment: "Slightly undefined".  I may steal that and use it for my own purposes in the future :)

Comment: Feel free to. :)

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Okay I won't. Never even planned to. :-|

Answer (score 5):

You are actually reducing the allocated space, not increasing it. Both `malloc`
and `realloc` take the size in **bytes** that you want to allocate / resize. And
the size in bytes for an `int` is `size * sizeof(int)`.

You `realloc` call should look like this:

```
int *tmp = realloc(arr, size_arr * sizeof *tmp);
if(tmp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    // arr is left intact, the memory is still allocated

    // Error handling, for example
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

arr = tmp;
```

now you have space for `size_arr` integers.

Note that is a good practice to use a temp variable for storing the result of
`realloc`. When `realloc` fails, the original memory is **not** freed, so if you
don't use a temp variable, then you are losing the pointer to the orginal
memory.

Also, [don't cast `malloc` and `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).